# Show "loading" box only if AJAX call takes more than 500 milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make so that when an AJAX request takes more than 500 milliseconds, a "loading" div shows up. When the request is done, the div gets hidden again.

The code I'm using is below. It should work, but it doesn't. Why is that?

```
var timer;
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function () {
        timer && clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#loading').show();
        }, 500);
    },
    ajaxStop: function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('#loading').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it a cross domain request? The events don't fire for those.

Comment: No, it's not a cross-domain request.

Comment: How does it fail? Does it get to the callbacks at all? That is, if you put an alert / console.log / breakpoint inside your ajaxStart function, does it hit?

Comment: Yes, the callbacks work. There must be a problem with the timeouts. The "loading" div shows up when I remove the clearTimeout() function from ajaxStop.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you use the documented usage of the methods rather than `on()`. These are ajax events not dom events

```
$(document).ajaxStart( function () {
        timer && clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#processing').show();
        }, 500);
}).ajaxStop( function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('#processing').hide();       
});
```

Reference: [$.ajaxStart() docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

If you still have problems do some deeper analysis of differences in time when the 2 events trigger

Comment: It doesn't work. The difference in time seems legit.

Comment: does that element exist when the ajax fires? Is there only one of that id in page? Do the 2 events fire? Hard to troubleshoot without more feedback

Comment: Yes, it does exist. In fact, if I simplify the code so that it only shows and hides the element (without using any timeouts), it works fine. There is only one element with such ID. Firebug doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: ok so create a date inside the timeout...and see what diff is when stop fires...or a log timer. Keep in mind the ajax completion vs display of a whole bunch of data can be different

Answer (score 1):

For me, your code is working just fine:

```js
$(function() {
  var timer, d;
  $('#processing').hide();
  
  $(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() {
      console.log('started');
      d = performance.now();
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#processing').show();
      }, 300);
    },
    ajaxStop: function() {
      console.log('finished in ' + (performance.now() - d));
      clearTimeout(timer);
      $('#processing').hide();
    }
  });
  
  $('#load').on('click', function(e) {
    $.get('https://api.github.com/repos/joyent/node/issues?state=closed').then(function(res) {
      $('#result').html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 2) + '</pre>');
    });
  });
  
  $('#load2').on('click', function(e) {
    $.get('https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/issues?state=closed').then(function(res) {
      $('#result').html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 2) + '</pre>');
    });
  });
  
  $('#load3').on('click', function(e) {
    $.get('https://api.github.com/users/buzinas').then(function(res) {
      $('#result').html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 2) + '</pre>');
    });
  });
  
  $('#clear').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#result').html('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='load'>Load node.js closed issues</button><button id='load2'>Load Bootstrap closed issues</button><button id='load3'>Load Buzina's Github Profile</button><button id='clear'>Clear resuts</button>
<img id='processing' width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7">
<div id="result"></div>
```

First time you try to load the libraries, it will take more than 300ms, and the image will be shown. Second time, they will be cached by the browser, and will take less than 300ms, and the image will not. You can see what's happening inside your console.

Probably, already in the first time you try to load my profile, it will take less than 300ms, and the image will not be shown as well.

Note: I've changed to `300ms` only for testing purposes, because maybe faster connections won't take 500ms to load the Github api.